# Salary Discrepancy

Tags: salary, united-kingdom

I work as a software engineer in the UK. When I applied for the job, there was no salary advertised. They are currently advertising the same role at double what I was offered. I've asked my manager if I was lowballed. Do I have any rights to ask for a higher salary?

Comment: "I've asked my manager if I was lowballed."  What was his answer to your question?

Comment: Still waiting for an answer.

Comment: You should also ask the level of seniority of that "same role". The job post might be boilerplate but the actual role at a higher level.

Comment: Did you not speak to your peers in the same industry on salaries?

Comment: If you accepted a contract at supposed half of market value, then that's on you. If you didn't see that job posting, you would've still been clueless on your market worth. Employers have no responsibility to tell you what your market worth is; they can only offer contracts to what it is worth to *them*.

Answer (score 19):

- You have the right to ask.
- Your employer has the right to say "no".
- You have the right to find another job.

To answer the implicit question: you have no right to a higher salary just because they're advertising a role at a higher salary, unless you can show that you are being discriminated against due to a [protected characteristic](https://www.equalityhumanrights.com/en/equality-act/protected-characteristics).

Comment: To add to this, this is a good lesson for OP on salary negotiation for future jobs. If you're not sure what you should be paid you should be browsing similar jobs for that role and using online resources to determine that. This is all assuming that the posted job that OP mentioned has the same requirements (experience level, stack, etc) as their current job.